# Google maps v3 displaying wrong directions and text either

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I have google maps V3 in my website and trying to get directions between two place, in which i will pass one address as text and another address latitude and longitude to the google route function as below:

```
   oRequest = {
        origin: address in string text format,
        destination: latlng object,
        travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
    };

    g_oDirections.route(oRequest, function (response, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
            g_oDirectionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
        }
        else { CreateDefaultMap(); }
    });
```

It is displaying wrong text(for destination) in the set of html returned by google, which will show the text saying A and B(destination) with some way points in between.

when i tried the same in google maps that worked fine, i debugged all my code till calling the google api function everything is fine say, passing latlng object and address as text.

any work around plz..

Comment: When you say the "wrong text (for destination)",  do you it is displaying an address but not the one you expect?

Comment: yes, it is displaying some wrong stuff. Any ways I have to manipulate the destination address, so do you have any idea how to pass/change the directions text displayed(which we will get from google getdirections service).

Comment: What is "some wrong stuff"?

Answer (score 0):

Check this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yZZdk/), it works for me.

```
var start = "Brno";     //Set the source/ origin
var end = new google.maps.LatLng(50, 15);  //Set the destination
var request = {
    origin:start,
    destination:end,
    travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
};
```

Maybe there is a problem with specific places which you send to the direction service. I had these problems a few times. If that's the case, post the place and coordinates.

Comment: I didn't see any difference between your code and mine. Even its working for some places for me. Do you think getting co-ordinates for the address and pass them instead of a text, will solve this. What did you do when you have this problem @Pohoda